# how to test masking of input field functionality through webdriver

Tags: java, extjs, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Hi i want to test whether the password field is masking the entered string in password field. how can i test it throught webdriver. i have tried below thing :

```
package unitTest.JUnitTestCases;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class PasswordTest 
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/form/adv-vtypes.html");
        WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.id("textfield-1014-inputEl"));
        username.sendKeys("admin");
        System.out.println(username.getText());
        WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.id("textfield-1015-inputEl"));
        password.sendKeys("admin");
        System.out.println(password.getAttribute("textContent"));
        //WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
    }
}
```

Here i am entering the some value in the password field and trying to get the text entered in that field so that i will check whether it is masked or not.
TIA!!

Comment: Is the line 
`System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("textfield-1015-inputEl")).getAttribute("type"));`
returning output as "password" ?

Comment: Why would you do this? That's the responsibility of the browser to mask the password fields. You don't have to test the browser, but to test your application!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do that, but I doubt it. Because this is a browser-level thing to me, which means browsers should take care of `<input type="password">`.

One solution is to use some kind of screenshot comparing tool.

One other solution is to check if the input has attribute `type="password"`, if it has, then you can assume your site is generated correctly, but this doesn't mean that browser handles it right.

```
System.out.println(password.getAttribute("type").equals("password"));
```

Note that `password.getAttribute("value")` will get you the characters you type in anyway. (which is like I said, password masking is browser's ability, the text will be there as value, browser hides it from user)

Side note: Don't use `By.id("textfield-1014-inputEl")` for ExtJS. Try use meaningful class names like `By.cssSelector(.x-form-type-password:nth-of-type(1) input[type="password"])`.

Comment: Hi all we have migrated our application to this new ExtJS framework hence just wanted to test whether things are working as expected. But you guys are sure right? that it is the responsibility of the browser and not that of the technology for masking of password field? please correct me as i don't know much about that. TIA