# can we check that text in password field is displayed masked?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can we verify whether the text which is written in **PASSWORD** field is being displayed in **masked** format or not?

Comment: "Encrypted format"???? I assume you mean is replaced by asterisk's?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea (assuming that you're using `WebDriver driver`):

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("..."));
boolean isEncrypted = input.getAttribute("type").equals("password");
```

You'll need to replace the `...` with the exact value of the password input box ID.

Comment: I guess OP wants to check `*****` (as human see), which is the ability of browsers, has nothing to do with Selenium. What you are suggesting is to check input is password field in an HTML source code sense, which doesn't necessarily show up as `*****`. An earlier of mine is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333253/1177636).

Comment: user1177636: Well, OP tagged this question with Selenium, so I suggested an idea that involved using Selenium.